# Custom Task : TaskHost parameters persistence

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am currently developing a custom task and I'm stuck on a problem.

My Custom Task consists of three files:

- MBTask that contains the class that implements the interface "Task"
- MBTaskUI that implements the interface "IDtsTaskUI"
- MBForm which is a Form.

In MBTaskUI on the Initialize() function i reveive the TaskHost object and save it in a variable. And then in the GetView() function o send this TaskHost to my Form builder

```
public void Initialize(TaskHost taskHost, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    this.taskHost = taskHost;
    IDtsConnectionService cs = serviceProvider.GetService
    (typeof(IDtsConnectionService)) as IDtsConnectionService;
    this.connections = cs.GetConnections();
}

public ContainerControl GetView()
{
    return new MBForm(this.taskHost, this.connections);
}
```

It work great and i can use this TaskHost in my Form to get parameters when i load the Form and save them when I close it.

```
String script_tmp = (String)th.Properties["myScript"].GetValue(th);
SqlConnection conn_tmp = (SqlConnection)th.Properties["myConnection"].GetValue(th);

th.Properties["myScript"].SetValue(th, myScript);                  
th.Properties["myConnection"].SetValue(th, myConnectionTarget);
```

And so, when i re-open my Task Editor, i use the parameters i received to initialize some objects.

But, and here is my problem, in my MBTask class, i have a Validate() function which verify the parameters (myConnection and myScript). and these parameters are always null (also after I normally initialized it by using the MBForm and the close function.

So, what I don't understand is why my parameters were not instanced ?
Isn't it the job of "th.Properties["myScript"].SetValue(th, myScript);" ?

myScript and myConnection are declared public in my MBTask.

```
public class MBTask : Task
{
    public SqlConnection myConnection { get; set; }
    public String myScript { get; set; }
```

I know these parameters are saved because i can get them back when i re-open the editor. So why are they null when I do the Validate() ?

Do I have to add a link to the TaskHost from the MBTaskUI and the one from the MBTask ?

It seems that there is something i don't understand here ...

Thanks for your help,

Léo Lejeune.

Comment: After investigation i understood that UI and Task are totally separated component.

So, how can i get the properties i defined with the Form (and TaskHost) ?
I can see them in property panel (myScript & myConnection) when i click on my component after i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I fond the solution:

The system I implemented was correct. But if you want to use complex parameters (SQLConnection) you have to use XML saving.

So, to use the default saving parameter of the task, only use simple objects like String and Integer.

And the Validate function can't use parameters because they are not yet instanced and so they are null.